# How can I fix this undefined method error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am integrating Postmark's transactional email service into my web application so that when a user signs up, my application sends the user a welcome email. When I try to signup as a user, I get the following error: undefined method `postmark_settings=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class

In my config/application.rb file, I have the following code:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method   = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => "my_api_key" }
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error or how I can go about fixing it. If I haven't provided enough useful information to solve the problem, just let me know and I'll add whatever code might be useful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the line below in your Gemfile?

```
gem 'postmark-rails', '0.4.0'
```

There are similar issues where people haven't included this line on the Gemfile...

Also, are you using Rails 3? The configuration in different between Rails 2 and 3. Please note details [here](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails).

Comment: I have included the gem in my Gemfile, except the version I use is 0.9.12. In my Gemfile, I have the Gem in my assets group. Should I switch the group in which the gem is located? I'm using Rails 3, and followed the setup guide on the Postmark Rails page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: try removing the gem from the assets group and place it outside of any group.

Comment: @user1483441 I don't think it should be in assets; isn't it a library?

Comment: I placed the gem outside of any group, and I still got the same error.